# measurability of functions; sub sigma field and completion

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr　F, \mu)$ be a measure space, and $\mathscr G$  be a sub $\sigma$-field of $\mathscr　F$.

And let $f:\Omega \to \mathbf R$ be a function, and $g:\Omega \to \mathbf R$ be  a $\mathscr　G$-measurable function such that

$$f=g \;\text{ $\mu$- a.e.}$$

Then, is $f $ a $\overline{\mathscr　G} $-measurable function ?, where

$$ \overline{\mathscr　G} = \{A \subset \Omega \mid  \exists B \in \mathscr　G, A  \triangle B \text{ is a $\mu$-null set }\} .$$

I know it is true that $f $ is $\hat{\mathscr　G }$-measurable, where $\hat{\mathscr　G }= \{A \subset \Omega \mid  \exists B \in \mathscr　F, A  \triangle B \text{ is a $\mu$-null set }\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. If $I$ is an interval let $C$ and $D$ be the inverse images under $f$ and $g$. Then $C\Delta D$ is a $\mu$ null set and $D$ is in $\mathscr G$. The desired measurability follows.

Comment: Thank you for answering. If we replace "$\mu$- null set" in the definition of $\overline{\mathscr{G}}$ by  "$\left.\mu \right|_{\mathscr{G}}$ -null set", then is the statement also true ?